# How to limit/restrict accessing android device through adb

Tags: android

Is there any possible way that adb can connect to only one device ?
Actually my requirement is android device should connect only from one IPAddress.

**Usecase 1:**
Only below system ip should access android device. 
System IP(PC): 10.0.0.2 
adb connect 10.0.0.4 - Android device 
Result: Successfully connected

**Usecase 2:**
Below system ip should fail to connect to device. 
System IP(PC): 10.0.0.6 
adb connect 10.0.0.4 - Android device 
Result: Failed to connect.

Finally only one IPAddress have to access android device.

Comment: This seems like it would do better in [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) than SO to me.